# Exception handler makes variable unusable

Tags: java, exception

This is a piece of my code:

```
if (1 == wahl)
    do{
        // Anzahl Spieler
        int anzahlSpieler = IOTools.readInteger("Geben Sie Anzahl Spieler  ein: ");
        Spieler[] spieler = new Spieler[anzahlSpieler];

        for ( int j = 0; j < anzahlSpieler; j++) {
            spieler[j] = new Spieler("aktueller Spieler "+j);
        }

        Wuerfel wuerfelWurf = new Wuerfel();
```

Now, when I add an exception handler, like this:

```
if (1 == wahl)
    do{
        // Anzahl Spieler
        int anzahlSpieler = IOTools.readInteger("Geben Sie Anzahl Spieler  ein: ");
        try{
            Spieler[] spieler = new Spieler[anzahlSpieler];
        } catch (NegativeArraySizeException e){
            System.err.print("Unzulaessige Eingabe: +    e.getMessage());
        }

        for ( int j = 0; j < anzahlSpieler; j++) {
            spieler[j] = new Spieler("aktueller Spieler "+j);
        }

        Wuerfel wuerfelWurf = new Wuerfel();
```

Every `spieler` variable from below catch until the end of the whole code is marked red and there's written: "spieler cannot be resolved as a variable". However there are no errors at the try and catch statements.
What am I doing wrong?

PS: The exception is a "NegativeArraySizeException"

Comment: If you are using eclipse. It should be warm you about to unreachable and  initialize it.

Comment: Please put some effort into formatting your code - it's *really* hard to read at the moment. (I'd also recommend using `if (wahl == 1)` instead of `if (1 == wahl)`; there's no benefit in the latter in Java, and most people find it easier to read conditions where the vairable part comes first in a comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare 'spieler' variable out of the try block.

> Variables declared inside try block can be accessible within block only.So declare the variable out of try block and assign it in try block.

Comment: I would add that OP should check that `anzahlSpieler ` is no less than 0.

Answer (score 0):

The variable is known only in the scope of the try block.
you should declare him outside of the try block and then it will be ok...

Answer (score 0):

```
if (1 == wahl)                 
    do{
       // Anzahl Spieler
          int anzahlSpieler = IOTools.readInteger("Geben Sie Anzahl Spieler  ein: ");
          Spieler[] spieler;  //declare variable outside try block so it is accessible
          try{
               spieler = new Spieler[anzahlSpieler];  //initialize the variable here to catch any exceptions
          }

          catch (NegativeArraySizeException e){
               System.err.print("Unzulaessige Eingabe: +    e.getMessage());
          }

          for ( int j = 0; j < anzahlSpieler; j++)
          {
                spieler[j] = new Spieler("aktueller Spieler "+j);
          }

          Wuerfel wuerfelWurf = new Wuerfel();
```

A variable declared in a block is a local variable for that block. It has no existence outside that block. So you are not able to access `spieler` variable outside the `try` block.

The above code will solve your problem. But if you want to access the `spieler` variable outside `if` block too, you will need to declare it before the `if` block.